# javascript example breaking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a javascript that has onchange event bind to my "type" select drop down. Why is it not working can some one help ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            onChangeType = function () {
                alert(this);
            };
            $('#type').bind('change', onChangeType);
        })();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <select id="type" type="text/javascript">
            <option value="1">test1</option>
            <option value="2">test2</option>
            <select id="sel">
            </select>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Self-invoking function !== document ready handler.

Comment: Honest common newb question, not sure why downvoted instead of referred to one of the many duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the handler in the document.ready handler. You're binding to the element before the element exists in the DOM.

```
onChangeType = function() {
    alert(this);
}

$(function() {
    $('#type').on('change', onChangeType);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#type').bind('change',function(){
      alert(this);
  });
});
</script>
```